# Re-inventing the wheel: Binary search in Scala

Tags: algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel, scala, binary-search

I am trying to implement the code described in [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-giant-sites-like-Reddit-verify-that-a-username-isnt-taken-so-fast) about how Reddit uses binary search to identify duplicate user names, in Scala. Just to clarify, this is mainly for me figuring out how these things work, i.e. *reinventing the wheel*. The way I understand it, the steps for binary search are:

1. You have a **new user name** you are comparing to an alphabetically sorted **list of existing names**
2. You compare that new name to the **middle item** in the list.
3. If there is no match, you check if the new name is higher or lower in the alphabet than the middle item, and focus **on this side** of the list, again checking the middle item.
4. You **repeat** until there is a match (*"User name taken"*) or none (*"User name available"*).

Below is what I have. It seems to work when I test it on the names in the list and random other names. It'd cool if someone had some feedback re:

- Will this work correctly or is there some kind of bug?
- Is there anything really un-Scalaesque in here? I'm just starting out...
- Is the `while` loop the right way to go? Are there better options?
- I think the comparer pattern matching function should be expanded to do more, i.e. cover different cases of non-matching, but I couldn't quite get there..
- Any other comments are much appreciated!

-

```
//this is my test data
val lines = List("ally", "ben", "albert", "zong", "hermit", "??ennis", "123pat", "alfred", "zil", "zol", "zal")

def comparer(name_one:String, name_two:String): Boolean = name_one match 
    //comparer takes two strings, returns true if identical
    {
    case `name_two` => true
    case _ => false
    }


def checker(new_name: String, old_names: List[String]) : Boolean =
    //checker takes a new user name, compares to List of names already in use
    //returns true if already present or false if not
    {
    val sortednames:List[String] = old_names.sorted
    println(new_name + "input list is length " + sortednames.length)

    //set vars, initialize
    var found: Boolean = false
    var startpoint: Int = 0
    var endpoint: Int = sortednames.length-1
    //while loop, breaks when something is found
    while (found == false && startpoint < endpoint)
    {
        println("start: "+startpoint+" end: "+endpoint)
        //set the midpoint were checking against
        var mid: Int = (startpoint + endpoint) / 2
        println("mid is " + mid)
        //run comparer to set found var initialized abpve
        found = comparer (new_name, sortednames(mid))   
        println("new name " + new_name)
        println("ist window " + sortednames(mid))
        //check if new_name is higher or lower in alphabet than mid
        if (new_name > sortednames(mid)) {
            startpoint = mid +1
            println("set start to " + startpoint)
            }
        if (new_name < sortednames(mid)) {
            endpoint = mid
            println("set end to " + endpoint)
    }
    }
    found
    }

val x:Boolean =checker("ally", lines)

println("checker returns ")
println(x)
```

Comment: For user base of 1 billion users, your function would use approximately 30 billion comparisons, not 30

Comment: @enedil eh that is unfortunate / terrible! Is it because I do the `while` and the two `if`s? And do you have any hints of how to do that better? Thanks!

Comment: it's because you sort the list at the beginning of the function. You have to assume it's already sorted - just keep it sorted

Comment: @patrick, it looks like there is a bug in this code. Have you checked if `checker()` returns `true` when `new_name` matches the last value in the sorted list? ("zong" in your example)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a number of things that are very un-Scalaesque, chief among them:

- mutable variables - using `var` instead of `val`
- `while` loop - recursion is usually preferred
- basic comparison operators can be used on strings - `>`, `<`, `==`, etc.

There are also efficiency issues to be considered:

- indexing into a `List` is slow - `Vector` and `Array` collections are better
- mixed binary search - many implementations abandon the binary search and go into a straight linear search when the field of candidates becomes small enough.

With a few of these things in mind, here's an alternative approach. (A full binary search, just for simplicity.)

```
def checker(name: String, names: Seq[String]) : Boolean = {
  // sort the input once, use Array for fast indexing
  val arr: Array[String] = names.sorted.toArray

  // tail-recursive binary search for name in names
  def search(start: Int = 0, end: Int = arr.length -1): Boolean = {
    val mid = start + (end-start)/2
    if (start > end)           false                // can't be found
    else if (arr(mid) == name) true                 // found
    else if (arr(mid) > name)  search(start, mid-1) // narrow the field
    else                       search(mid+1, end)
  }
  search()  // do it
}
```

Result:

```
val lines = List("ally", "ben", "albert", "zong", "hermit", "??ennis", "123pat", "alfred", "zil", "zol", "zal")
checker("zong", lines)  // res0: Boolean = true
checker("zing", lines)  // res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: I think `val mid = (end+start)/2` is better

Comment: @tom10271; That is more direct and to-the-point, but for sufficiently large values of `start` and `end`, the shorter version will encounter `Int` overflow and thus incorrect (negative) results. That won't happen with the longer version. Not likely to be an issue in this case but still worth considering.

Comment: Good point to consider